# How to replace patterns in files contained in a list of files?

Tags: bash, replace

I have a text file `fileslist` containing a list of names of files, or rather relative paths to those files and their names from a certain parent directory. There is only one file per line in `fileslist`. From that parent directory I want to run a command on every single file one by one. This command should search the entire every single one of those files for a pattern, and replace it with another pattern. Each of these text files may or may not contain the pattern `College Documents`. I want to replace it with `College_Documents`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend `xargs` for this:

```
xargs sed -i 's/College Documents/College_Documents/g' < filelist
```

This tells xargs to read its input from `filelist` (where it would normally read from stdin; we're giving it the contents of the file, instead). It fills up `sed`'s parameter list with as many files as will fit, executing for example:

```
sed -i 's/College Documents/College_Documents/g' file1 file2 file3 ...
sed -i 's/College Documents/College_Documents/g' filen filem fileo ...
```

Answer (score 1):

After some researching, I found that this command works well for my purposes.

```
cat fileslist | while read in; do sed -i 's/College Documents/College_Documents/g' $in; done
```